# JXL - setRowView do nothing

Tags: android, jxl

I am trying to change the size of rows and columns, with JXL library.
Here is my code :

```
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setDrawingsDisabled(false);

File xlsFile = new File(fileName);
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(xlsFile, wbSettings);
WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("0First Sheet", 0);

sheet.setColumnView(0, 40);
sheet.setRowView(0, 40);

workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

Here is the result : Column width has changed, but not the row height. I tried multiples way, row height never changed. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK now this is working, I simply added some random content to the file

```
sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 3, "BB"));
```

Apparently changing height of rows cant be done on an empty table...